# Real life example of C UNIONS

Tags: c, unions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unions in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/unions-in-c)

I have been asked in an interview to give a real life example of unions. I suggested him unions can be used in low level system programming.He asked me give an example related to it. I told we can use union to find machine's byte order but he did not seem to be impressed at all.I mean what example i could have suggested to him that relates unions to real life??

Thanks.