# How to instantly check the zero value of a structure without checking its each element?

Tags: c++, performance, structure, zero

Suppose I have a `byte` structure, like this :

```
struct one_byte
{
char b1 : 1,
     b2 : 1,   
     b3 : 1,   
     b4 : 1,   
     b5 : 1,   
     b6 : 1,   
     b7 : 1,   
     b8 : 1;   
}foo;
```

In some cases I'll need to check `(foo == 0)`, then I have to do eight commands :

```
if(foo.b1 == 0 &&
   foo.b2 == 0 &&
   foo.b3 == 0 &&
...and so on
```

Is there any portable & convenient way which can instantly check zero value only with a single command? I tried functions & templates, they perform very slowly. And I tried union, my compiler doesn't support bit[array]....

Comment: You could use `std::bitset`. A function shouldn't have any (noticeable) difference over all 8 statements without the call, though.

Comment: You can try using macro, eg: `#define IS_ZERO(var) if(var.b1==0 && var.b2 == 0...)`

Comment: My real structure is complex, so assigning and checking by `std::bitset` is slow (tested).

Comment: [union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions)

Comment: @gerrytan : A single command, not a macro. (eight commands again...)

Comment: `memcmp` to all zeroes?

Comment: @Patashu, look at my comment for @dreamlax about `memcmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions), this is what it is intended for

```
union {
  struct {
    char b1:1,b2:1,b3:1,b4:1,b5:1,b6:1,b7:1,b8:1; 
  } bits;
  unsigned char byte;
} u;
```

then you can either assign directly the *byte*

```
u.byte = 15;
```

or the bits individually

```
u.bits.b3 = 1;
```

*Exemple*

```
int main() {
  u.byte = 0;
  printf("%x\n", u.byte);
  u.bits.b3 = 1;
  u.bits.b4 = 1;
  printf("%x\n", u.byte);
  return 0;
}
```

will output

```
0
c  // 12 in decimal, since b3 and b4 are set to 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct one_byte zero = { 0 };

!memcmp (&variable_1, &zero, sizeof (struct one_byte))
```

Could be a solution, but I don't know if it is such a clever idea.
Maybe just unsing the more or less standard way of bit-setting would do better:

```
#define SET_BIT(v, n) (v) |= (1<<n)
#define CLR_BIT(v, n) (v) &= ~(1<<n)
#define GET_BIT(v, n) ((v) & ~(1<<n) == 0)

char foo;

if (foo == 0)
   so_what ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will provide any significant performance increase.

```
if (memcmp(&foo, "\0", 1) == 0)
{
    // all zero
}
```

I don't have the C++ spec on hand but the C99 spec 6.7.2.1/13 says (emphasis mine):

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, **points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides)**, and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, **but not at its beginning**.

Comment: `memcmp` isn't a good idea, because of padding bytes while alignment. In general, not in this particular case

Comment: @borisbn: There can be **NO** padding at the beginning of a struct, only *between* members or at the end.

Comment: In this **particular case** - when you copmare only 1 byte - my comment has no sense, and of course, there couldn't be padding bytes at the beginning of the struct/union. But in general, it would be better to avoid `memcmp`. Do you agree ?

Comment: You could compare against a `one_byte` with all fields zeroed to avoid the problem that @borisbn has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
struct one_byte{
  char b1:1;
  char b2:1;
  char b3:1;
  char b4:1;
  char b5:1; 
  char b6:1;
  char b7:1;
  char b8:1;
    }__attribute__((packed));

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  one_byte b1;
  int j;
  memcpy(&j, &b1, sizeof(b1)); 
  if(j == 0) cout << "Its 0";
  else cout << "It's not 0";
  return 0;
}
```

what about the above program?

Comment: Look at my comment for @dreamlax about `memcmp`

Answer (score 0):

```
!*((unsigned char *) &foo)
```

Should do the trick. Notice that I used the `!` operator to check for zero value -- if you don't like that, feel free to use `== 0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to get down and dirty, so how about:

```
struct one_byte Other; // a real variable
...   
if(*(char*)&Other == '\0')
```

Comment: aaaaa... is right: unsigned is more portable, although it's hard to say "portable" with a straight face when we've already stooped this low :-)