# How to easily extract 2x int16 from a int32?

Tags: c

I have a variable that have 2x int16 values as:

```
int32_t value = 0x1234ABCD; // a=0x00001234, b=0xFFFFABCD
```

The naive solution is to do a mask:

```
int32_t a = (value & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
int32_t b = (value & 0x0000FFFF);
```

But with this, I don't have any sign expansion and b becomes `0x0000ABCD` instead of `0xFFFFABCD`.

My next attempt was to use an intermediate structure

```
struct dual_int16 {
   long hi:16;
   long lo:16;
}

int32_t a = (struct dual_int16)value).lo;
int32_t a = (struct dual_int16)value).hi;
```

Unfortunately my compiler doesn't allow me to do this "struct dual_int16 is not allowed" or "type of cast must be arithmetic or pointer".

Is there any correct way to extract my 2x int16 with sign expansion in C99?

**EDIT**

Because I am using a specific compiler (ADSP-21xxx) . I don't have all the standard types defined in `stdint.h` such as `int16_t`. My compiler does not recognize `int8_t` and `int16_t`.

The arch has an hybrid 32-48bits dual ALU, big endian.

Comment: Did you try casting to `int16_t` before converting to 32 bits?

Comment: You might want to try to store the 16-bit values in a 16-bit type.

Comment: What makes you think `0x1234ABCD & 0x0000FFFF` should become `0xFFFFABCD`?

Comment: You want int16 but define result as int32. The result is normal.

Comment: @BennoZeeman Because I store 2x int16. `0xABCD`= -21555. If you do the sign expansion the final value become `0xFFFFABCD` = -21555

Comment: @coin What compiler has `int32_t`, but no `int16_t`?

Comment: ok. so maybe you need to write arch specific code. maybe you could offer us the endianness info, length of `short`, `int` and `long`, and what standard library you have.

Comment: maybe we can investigate more. is right shift in your compiler arithmetic or logic?

Comment: It can be both depending on a configuration bit. I can of course use an assembly macro that do the trick. But I am looking for a more portable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`union` will do the trick.

```
union {
    int32_t value;
    struct {
        int16_t v1, v2;
    } decomp;
} extract;

/* ... */
extract.value = value;
int32_t a = extract.decomp.v1, b = extract.decomp.v2;
```

notice that, `a` and `b` have desired signs.

Comment: Might work, but more work and more error-prone than the manual masking and shifting. Not all the world is little-endian.

Comment: @Deduplicator yeah. actually in big endian, it will do the trick too. but `v1` and `v2` are in reversed order. not necessary to be more error-prone than manual shift, since they are actually the same.

Comment: Never read a member that has been written to by another member.

Comment: You're only supposed to read the field which was most recently written.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find it in the standard at the moment. But I have [an answer that backs me up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/252568/2703418).

Comment: @BennoZeeman not in c99 anymore, because value touch the whole union you are allowed to read from v1 and v2. Reading value after writing to v1 is not allowed.

Comment: @BennoZeeman decomposing bit/byte sequence using `union` is a regular trick in C, heavily used in low layer programming.

Comment: C99, 6.2.6.1: "When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.". I'm a bit lost now, but I'm pretty sure people should avoid it if they can. Low layer programming is different, because usually you're targeting a specific architecture etc.

Comment: @BennoZeeman yeah. sometimes people will avoid that, if you are defining a `union` to represent a selection. that is something like `struct { enum myenum choice; union { /* some structs */ } value; }`. but in my case, it has to work in this way. not necessary to target a specific arch, if you are decomposing a stream in TCP/IP, you will be happy to use `union` too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want signed 16-bit values, use the proper type:

```
#include <stdint.h>

const int32_t value = 0x1234ABCD; // a=0x00001234, b=0xFFFFABCD

const int16_t a = (value >> 16) & 0xffff;
const int16_t b = value & 0xffff;

printf("a=%hd\nb=%hd\n", (short) a, (short) b);
```

This prints:

```
a=4660
b=-21555
```

Also note that I shift before I mask, to reduce the literal size of the masks. This is probably pointless with modern smart optimizing compilers, but that's the reason I changed it.

I used `int16_t` since you used `uint32_t` and mentioned C99, that really made me believe you should have it. Make sure you `#include <stdint.h>`.

Comment: If OP needs to store them into `int32_t`, I guess you could implicitly cast `int16_t` to `int32_t` by `int32_t a = (uint16_t)((value >> 16) & 0xffff);`.

Comment: I really don't get the `(uint16_t)` cast there, that's not what you said you wanted to do ... I'm quite skeptical to this suggestion.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I meant `int16_t`. I think you confused me by mentioning `uint32_t` in your answer. Oh dear.

Comment: Regarding reducing the literal size, you wouldn't want to do `(value & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> 16` anyhow, because right-shifting a negative integer is implementation defined behavior: you don't know whether it will fill up with zeroes (logical shift) or with the sign bit (arithmetic shift). The code you have written avoids this issue since you mask away the unwanted bits _after_ the shift.

Comment: @Lundin That's true, and perhaps another reason I switched to this pattern a long time ago. :) Thanks.

Comment: Oh and btw... nobody expects implicit integer promotion! A hex literal larger than 0x7fff is actually of unsigned type on a 16 bit system. This means that `value & 0xffff` will get promoted to an unsigned type, since 0xffff is then actually of type unsigned int. This could potentially cause a bug, but as far as I can see this particular code will be okay. Mixing signed integers with bitwise operators is always dangerous.

Answer (score -2):

```
short a = (short)( (value >> 16) & 0xFFFF );
short b = (short)( value & 0xFFFF );
```

`int32_t` is not a standard type, as well (comment to @coin). `short/short int` is equivalent of `int16_t`.

Comment: What do you mean by int32_t is not a standard type? sizeof( short ) could be > 2.

Comment: Might be, or might not be equivalent. And it's a *standard*-typedef, if the implementation has a fitting type, in C99 (and probably back-ported).

Comment: It is comment from above: "Unfortunately int16_t doesn't exists with my compiler". For that reason I say that int32_t is also not a normal type.