# declare a variable with different types in C++

Tags: c++

how can i declare a variable with different types in C++

```
 struct maxKernelBetTwoVec
 {
     size_t  Elem1;
     double Elem2;
  };
```

so Elem2 can be int, or double, or string.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. Why do you want that?

Comment: You must use a union

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions

Comment: While a union is good, and probably the best answer here, you could always just declare a `void * Elem2` and treat it how you like, allocating the memory you need and then deleting that and reallocating it to suit another type of variable. Although personally that just seems like a lot of work, I'd rather just create multiple variables (kinda how unions work).

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Several solutions. Need more more information about how you plan to use this in order to provide a worthwhile answer.

Comment: @ eyllanesc, @ chbchb55 thnx that help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union), but they are hard to use correctly and safely. A far better option is to use a [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
struct maxKernelBetTwoVec
{
    size_t Elem1;
    std::variant<int, double, std::string> Elem2;
};
```

Unfortunately, `std::variant` is only available in C++17. If you can't yet use `std::variant`, you can use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) instead.

Comment: thnx alot, thats exactly what i need