# The "EOF" value in different type (an union)?

Tags: c, eof

I am reading the C book **K&R**. I know that **the macro `EOF` on my system is `-1`**.

```
int eof = EOF;
printf("EOF on my system is: %d\n",eof);
```

But when I assign `EOF` to a union, the output somehow confused me. I can only understand `v.ival` is `-1`. Anyone can explain why the rest of them: `v.cval`, `v.fval`, and `v.dval` would be like this?

```c
union eof_val {
    int ival;
    char cval;
    float fval;
    double dval;
} eof;

eof.ival = EOF;

printf("EOF to int = %d\n", eof.ival);        /* output: -1 */
printf("EOF to char = %c\n", eof.cval);       /* output: � */
printf("EOF to float = %f\n", eof.fval);      /* output: nan */
printf("EOF to double = %f\n", eof.dval);     /* output: 0.000000 */
```

Comment: reading `dval` results in undefined behavior because `int` is probably shorter than `double`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc  okey. but how to explain `cval`? `-1` in `int` occupies 4 bytes `0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF` in memory. thus `cval` should equals to `0xFF` right? which is `255` on ascii table?

Comment: undefined behavior means *anything can happen*, including [making demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). However in this case the character at code point 255 is printed out. `%c` is not for printing a char as its numeric value. Use `printf("%d\n", (char)eof.cval)` instead

Comment: for sure it will not print 255, but the 255th  character in ascii table. `0xFF` is the value on memory. am I right?

Comment: "a test, to have a look in memory." --> instead add member `unsigned char uc[sizeof double]` and print the elements of the array in hex to gain a better understanding.

Comment: good hint! thx @chux :>

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc    output for `printf("%d\n", (char)eof.cval)` is not `255` as expected, but still `-1`...

Comment: @weiShen it's because [`char` is signed by default on your platform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714). Change to `unsigned char` and see

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc    finally got `255`. thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A union is big enough to hold the biggest of it's members. It does not hold them all. Only one of it's values is usable at a time.

You've set `ival` and it's good, but that means `cval`, `fval` and `dval` pretty much hold rubbish (not quite: you could figure it out based on the value of `ival`)

Not a duplicate, but interesting reading: [Why do we need C Unions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions)