# Casting / accessing same memory are as different variables in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

If I have 4 bytes of memory and would like to access this memory as both unsigned long **L** and char **c[4]**. What would be the most efficient way to do this in C?

For example, if I set the **L** to 300 then the bytes will be set to **0x0000012c**, if I access the **c[3]** I would expect to see **0x2c**

If I increase **c[3]** by one, it becomes **0x2d** and **L** now has a value of 301

Thanks

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: You can do it using a `union`, but the results are implementation-defined if you read a different member than the last one written.

Comment: @Barmar: No, it is not, if done properly. The bytes of an object may be read and written through character types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions

Comment: Why would you expect `c[3]` to be `0x2c` instead of `0x00`?  endianness matters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil TiL! I didn't know it is defined in C.

Comment: @SergeyA Since type punning is a big no-no in C++ and I haven't used C in a long time, it's one of those things that now feels forbidden even when I do program in C. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `union` of the two types:

```
union u1 {
    unsigned long l;
    char c[sizeof(unsigned long)];
};
```

Then if you create a variable of the union type, you can write to one member and read the other.

Keep in mind however that the result depends on the *endianness* of your system.  Most x86 based systems are little-endian, meaning the least significant byte comes first.  If that's the case, the `c[0]` member would actually have the value `2c`.

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate the memory using a `union` and type punning:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    uint32_t L;
    char c[sizeof(uint32_t)];
} foo;

int main() {
    foo x;
    x.L = 123;
    printf("%X %X %X %X\n", x.c[0], x.c[1], x.c[2], x.c[3]);
}
```

The output will probably be `7B 0 0 0` or `0 0 0 7B` depending on the endianess of your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have memory that has been defined as an `unsigned long`, as with `unsigned long L;`, then you may access its bytes through a `char` value, as with:

```
char *c = (char *) &L;
printf("Byte 3 of L is %d.\n", c[3]);
```

This works because C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 says:

> … When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

and 6.5 7 says we can access any object through a character type:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> …
>
> — a character type.

This is also true for an `unsigned long` that was created by storing an `unsigned long` in allocated memory, as with `unsigned long *p = malloc(sizeof *p); *p = 300;`.

However, the order of the bytes in the `unsigned long` is implementation-defined. C requires unsigned integer types to use a pure binary notation but does not specify the order of the bits within the bytes or the bytes within the representation, and it also allows padding.

Also, it is generally preferable to use an `unsigned char` to access the bytes, rather than a `char`, to avoid potential complications with signedness. And note that character types are special in this regard, per the quotes from the standard above. Reinterpreting through other types is not generally supported in C, except with unions as described below.

If you just have “some memory,” say a special region in an embedded system, and you want to access it both as an `unsigned long` and a `char` as described above, then you may need support from your compiler beyond what the C standard. Of course, C implementations intended for use in embedded systems generally provide support for accessing such memory as needed.

However, even if you do not have a defined or allocated object and do not have special support from the compiler, you can put the bytes of an `unsigned long` in that memory by using character types. In particular, `memcpy` is defined to copy byte-by-byte, so it would serve:

```
unsigned long L = 300;       // Prepare a normal unsigned long.
memcpy(target, &L, sizeof L); // Copy bytes of L to the address in pointer "target".
```

Then, of course, you can also set a character pointer to point to the same place as `target` and use that pointer to access the bytes, as above.

Another way to use the same memory for two or more object types is through a union. This is defined in C but not C++:

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned long L;
    char c[4];
} MyUnion;
MyUnion x = { .L = 300 };
printf("Byte 3 of the unsigned long is %d.\n", x.c[3]);
```

This works because C 2018 6.5.2.3 3 tells us that the `.` operator accesses the value of the named member of the union, and note 99 makes it clear that, if the requested member is not the last one stored, “the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type”.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way to for that type of punning is the use of the `memcpy`. It is very likely that it will simple pointer pun the data when compiled using modern optimizing compilers.

```
type1 target = something;
type2 source = something_else;

#define MIN(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (b) : (a))

memcpy(&target, &source, MIN(sizeof(target), sizeof(source));
```

or if target and source are pointers

```
type1 *target = something;
type2 *source = something_else;

#define MIN(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (b) : (a))

memcpy(target, source, MIN(sizeof(*target), sizeof(*source));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want control over individual bytes of the unsigned long, I wouldn't recommend `char[4]` or `union` because they both make it endianness-specific.

You should instead do it with bitwise operations, since bitwise operations handle the endianness and you can just assume the bytes are written out as big-endian.

```
//  bytes: 0xFA_3E_12_99
//byte_ind:   3  2  1  0
unsigned long replace_nth_byte(unsigned long bytebuf, byte (*transform)(byte curr_byte), byte byte_ind) 
{
    byte curr_byte = (bytebuf >> byte_ind) & 0xFF;
    unsigned long bytes_infront = (bytebuf >> (byte_ind + 1)*8) << (byte_ind+1)*8;
    unsigned long bytes_inback = bytebuf & ((1 << byte_ind*8) - 1);
    byte transformed_byte = transform(curr_byte);
    bytebuf = (bytes_infront << (byte_ind + 1)*8) + bytes_inback;

    return bytebuf;
}
```