# How to store different types to allocated memory in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

My question is how to store different types to that memory and print it. specifically I need 3x char, 1x float, and 1x int.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `union`.

Comment: Aside `(uint16_t) malloc(5)` should be `(uint16_t*) malloc(5)` or just `malloc(5)`. But 5 bytes isn't enough to store those 5 items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need C Unions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions)

Comment: Thanks, I edited. I think I need pointers to those items.

Comment: If you're storing pointers, you can do an array of void pointers. If you're storing the actual values use a `union`.

Comment: If you need 5 pointers, then you want `void ** memory = malloc(5 * sizeof *memory)`.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but the type must be specifically uint16_t*.

Comment: @blazc these requirements make no sense. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Then the number of bytes allocated should be a multiple of `sizeof(uint16_t)` or `sizeof(*memory)`.  On most architectures an allocation of 5 is sufficient for only 2.5 `uint16_t`, which makes no sense.  It seems to me that you have narrowed this down to a XY problem; better to explain what you are actually trying to achieve.  BTW it is not necessary or advised to cast the return of malloc.

Comment: @Clifford I know it sounds strange, that was instruction in school. I don't really understand it aswell.

Comment: Yes, but clearly there was more to the assignment than you have revealed here.  Understanding that would help provide an appropriate answer.  Most assignments are looking to highlight specific learning; you could get a valid answer here that has no relationship to the course material, and going "off piste" no matter how elegant the solution may not get you a grade.  People here almost certainly know more than your tutor, but you need to give them what they are looking for, rather than necessarily what makes any sense.  In short a little more context would help.

Comment: @Clifford I'm going to ask the tutor to explain me the instruction. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without wider context about the assignment it is not possible to determine the solution your tutor is looking for, but to be clear `malloc()` returns a void pointer to memory guaranteed to be aligned in a manner that can be interpreted as any fundamental type.

The use of `uint16_t` here seems rather arbitrary, and is presumably chosen to test you knowledge of pointer concepts and type casts.  The strange choice of 5 byte length may also be contrived to highlight the fact that the space need only be large enough to hold the largest object to be stored.

This appears to be one of those tasks beloved of school assignments that do not necessarily encourage good coding practice.  That said, the following 'dirty' solution may be what is sought:

```
uint16_t* memory = (uint16_t*) malloc(5);

char* c = (char*)memory ;
c[0] = 'a' ;
c[1] = 'b' ;
c[2] = 'c' ;

float* f = (float*)memory ;
*f = 1.0 ;

int* i = (int*)memory ;
*i = 123 ;
```

A more sophisticated solution, that may be stepping beyond your course material is to use a union:

```
union
{
    uint16_t s ;
    char c[3] ;
    float f ;
    int i ;
}* memory = malloc( sizeof( *memory ) ) ;

memory->c[0] = 'a' ;
memory->c[1] = 'b' ;
memory->c[2] = 'c' ;

memory->f = 1.23 ;

memory->i = 123 ;
```

If the specific allocation line is "required" then you can use a named union and cast `memory`:

```
uint16_t* memory = malloc(5);
union variant
{
    char c[3] ;
    float f ;
    int i ;
} ;

((union variant*)memory)->f = 1.23 ;

((union variant*)memory)->i = 123 ;

((union variant*)memory)->c[0] = 'a' ;
((union variant*)memory)->c[1] = 'b' ;
((union variant*)memory)->c[2] = 'c' ;
```