# How to use a memory allocation with different variable types in c?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I would like to have memory allocated with different type of variables inside.

At the moment, I have this code:

```
    //key=4bytes(char), name= 4chars=4bytes, age=4bytes ==>12* 20 elements
    uint16_t * table = (uint16_t*)malloc(12*20);
    char* key = (char*) table ;
    char* name = (char*) table ;
    int* age = (int*)table ;
    key[0] = 'c';
    key[1] = 'i';
    key[2] = 'r';
    // key = "cir";
    // name = "pav";
    name[0] = 'p';
    name[1] = 'a';
    name[2] = 'v';
    *age = 15;

    char* key2 = (char*) table ;
    char* name2 = (char*) table ;
    int* age2 = (int*)table ;
    
    // key2 = "ric";
    // name2 = "vap";
    key2[0] = 'r';
    key2[1] = 'i';
    key2[2] = 'c';
    name2[0] = 'v';
    name2[1] = 'a';
    name2[2] = 'p';
    *age2 = 12;
```

I would like now to access (printf to screen) the different variables inside my memory, but I am not able to do this unless for the last element when I printf at the end of the code above:

```
printf("%d ", *(table));  // prints 12
```

I tried doing `*(table-4)` with %s or %c but nothings works always shows empty space if %c
or 0 if I try to find the number 15 by doing `*(table-12)`.

How can I access different values in my table **without using struct**.
I saw the declaration in this question: [How to store different types to allocated memory in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71442947/how-to-store-different-types-to-allocated-memory-in-c)

I want this:

[image]

Comment: Use a `union`..

Comment: what if I want to have multiple elements like an array. I want to have 20 elements where each one is key(4chars), name(4chars) and age(1byte).

Comment: Make the `union` members arrays of `int, char, ...`

Comment: Best to post a [mcve] to clearly understand what you are doing.

Comment: I want a hash table without using structs, the code I have is the one in the post. In my mind, I have a so called "table" with 2 elements.

Comment: All your variable point to the same address - you need to offset the variables. eg `name = key+4; age = name + 4; ...`

Comment: It's not clear to me if you understand that `key[0] = 'c'; name[0] = 'p';` causes the `'c'` to be overwritten.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(int)` may not be 4.  Making that assumption will eventually cause many errors.  In all of your calculations that make that assumption, just replace `4` with `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: You need to use a struct -- that's the whole reason it exists.

Comment: "I want a hash table without using structs" It's a meaningless exercise in futility.

Comment: @ChrisDodd The goal is to do it without the struct. Bad reddit ideas

Comment: A struct is just syntactic sugar for doing the pointer arithmetic yourself. Without a struct,  you need to actually do the pointer arithmetic, but you're not

Comment: You already linked a picture showing you know what the byte offsets should be, so apply them. You do this using `+` on a pointer with a suitable type

Comment: A struct where care about alignment has taken care of is identical to this, just easier to use. The only reason why you wouldn't use a struct is because you need to write something misaligned, like a data protocol to be sent over a bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your code to emulate an array of structures for learning purposes. Your code does not work because you write the different *fields* at the same address.  You should use different offsets for the different *fields* and different offsets for the successive entries. I suggest you write helper functions to initialize the *structured* elements one at a time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// copy a string with truncation
void pstrcpy(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src) {
    if (size) {
        while (*src && size-- > 1) {
            *dest++ = *src++;
        }
        *dest = '\0';
    }
}

void set_entry(char *e, const char *key, const char *name, int32_t age) {
    pstrcpy(e + 0, 4, key);
    pstrcpy(e + 4, 4, name);
    int32_t *p = (int32_t *)(e + 8);
    *p = age;
}

void print_entry(const char *e) {
    const char *key = e;
    const char *name = e + 4;
    const int32_t *age = (const int32_t *)(e + 8);
    printf("%s,%s,%ld\n", key, name, (long)*age);
}

int main() {
    char *table = malloc(12 * 20);
    if (table == NULL)
        return 1;

    set_entry(table + 0 * 12, "cir", "pav", 15);
    set_entry(table + 1 * 12, "ric", "vap", 12);
    // ...

    print_entry(table + 0 * 12);
    print_entry(table + 1 * 12);

    free(table);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking how to lay out a struct manually.  You can do that with casts and pointer arithmetic, but you need to be careful with padding and alignment.  You might do something like:

```
//key=4bytes(char), name= 4chars=4bytes, age=4bytes ==>12 bytes total
// 20 elements in an array, so equivalent to
// struct {
//     char key[4];
//     char name[4];
//     int age;
// } table[20];
void * table = malloc(12 * 20);

// setting element 0 of the table:
char* key = (char*)table + 0;
char* name = (char*)table + 4;
int* age = (int *)((char*)table + 8);
key[0] = 'c';
key[1] = 'i';
key[2] = 'r';
key[3] = 0;
// key = "cir";
// name = "pav";
name[0] = 'p';
name[1] = 'a';
name[2] = 'v';
name[3] = 0;
*age = 15;

// setting element 1
char* key2 = (char*)table + 12*1 + 0;
char* name2 = (char*)table + 12*1 + 4 ;
int* age2 = (int*)((char*)table + 12*1 + 8);

// key2 = "ric";
// name2 = "vap";
key2[0] = 'r';
key2[1] = 'i';
key2[2] = 'c';
key2[3] = 0;
name2[0] = 'v';
name2[1] = 'a';
name2[2] = 'p';
name2[3] = 0;
*age2 = 12;
```

Comment: Very poor way of doing it. No functions, no serialization

Comment: @gulpr: yes, but the whole point of the question seems to be to not use any abstractions, and expose all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this pointer bongo-mongo. Use `memcpy` and functions. You can get and set the whole record or particular fields. It is a bit more writing at the beginning, but it pays off when you debug and maintain your code. Also, you do not have to worry about alignment, padding, strict aliasing and another potential portability issues

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
    char key[4];
    char name[4];
    uint32_t age;   
}data_t;


void updateRecord(void *data, data_t *record, size_t pos)
{
    unsigned char *ucdata = data;
    
    memcpy(ucdata + pos * RECORDSIZE, record -> key, sizeof(record -> key));
    memcpy(ucdata + pos * RECORDSIZE + 4, record -> name, sizeof(record -> name));
    memcpy(ucdata + pos * RECORDSIZE + 8, &record -> age, sizeof(record -> age));
}

data_t getRecord(const void *data, size_t pos)
{
    const unsigned char *ucdata = data;
    data_t record;
    
    memcpy(&record.key, ucdata + pos * RECORDSIZE, sizeof(record.key));
    memcpy(&record.name, ucdata + pos * RECORDSIZE + 4, sizeof(record.name));
    memcpy(&record.age, ucdata + pos * RECORDSIZE + 8, sizeof(record.age));

    return record;
}

uint32_t getAge(const void *data, size_t pos)
{
    uint32_t age;
    const unsigned char *ucdata = data;

    memcpy(&age, ucdata + pos * RECORDSIZE + 8, sizeof(age));
    return age;    
}

void setAge(void *data, uint32_t age, size_t pos)
{
    unsigned char *ucdata = data;

    memcpy(ucdata + pos * RECORDSIZE + 8, &age, sizeof(age));
}
```